ROS2 ubuntu lunar purged but still preventing Ubuntu upgrade from 23.04 to 23.10
I have Ubuntu Linux 23.04 installed on my computer.  I had ROS2 Lunar Loggerhead installed on my computer, but then discovered it works better inside a VM, so I removed it using:
sudo apt-get remove ros-*

I just tried to update my system to Ubuntu 23.10 using:
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade

I get an error that says:
"E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file."

"N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default."

"N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details"

And the upgrade is stopped.
I tried sudo apt-get purge ros-* and I get the same issue.
What do I need to do in order to upgrade my Ubuntu to the latest version?
Thanks!

Back when you installed ROS2, folks who followed the instructions did this:

And then add the repository to your sources list:
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null

If you did it correctly, you created a file at /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list.
The reference(s) to lunar in that file is the cause of the error message. lunar = Ubuntu 23.04, which is no longer supported. That's why there is no release file.
If you don't want ROS2 anymore, then simply delete the file:
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list
If you want to retain ROS2, then edit the file, replacing all the lunar references with your current release (mantic).

Thanks for the help.  It worked... sort of.
It turns out that there were a number of files in that directory:
ros2.list
ros2.list.distUpgrade
ros2.list.save
I deleted them all and the update worked fine.
Thanks, again!!! I appreciate the help!
